# Create a scrapy spider. NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting started with Scrapy and I wanted to try out some tutorials to create a spider with Scrapy.

This is my code so far:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "quotes"

  def start_request(self):
      urls = [
          'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
          'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/'
      ]
      for url in urls:
          yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

  def parse(self, response):
      page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
      filename = "quotes-%s.html" % page
      with open(filename, "wb") as f:
          f.write(response.body)
      self.log('saved file %s' % filename)
```

As a report I get the following:

> ```
> Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
> >>> import scrapy
> >>> self.log('saved file %s' % filename)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'self' is not defined
> ```

I'm quite new to this and don't get how I can solve this. Hope you can help me. :)

Comment: can you check the indentation of `start_request` and `parse` functions

Comment: @Shijith should be right

Comment: Because `start_request` and `parse` are functions, I don't think the problem is them (the see `self` as local var). Please show us how you call it - looking at error and `stdin`, I assume you test it in the interactive interpreter, right? Please copy what you wrote there and everything it wrote back (including that error) and put in an edit to your question. :)

Comment: @h4z3 sorry I don't know what you mean by interactive interpreter :( I use VS Code and ran the code (it's the whole code here) and the Python Terminal gave back this error
I started with "scrapy startproject demo_project' and put the python file into the folder 'spiders' inside the project

Comment: I'm guessing you called `QuotesSpider.scrape` instead of `QuotesSpider().scrape`?

Comment: Please carefully check the indentation of your code. Python is running the last line `self.log('saved file %s' % filename)` first when it shouldn't be

Comment: @ItamarMushkin that doesn't fix the error unfortunately

Comment: a. What's the new error? b. Please share the code that runs the function, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Within the spider (not in the console), preferred syntax is `self.logger.info(message)`, or debug or whichever level you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `scrapy crawl quotes` in anaconda, from within the project directory, to start the spider

Comment: This answer should address your issue. You are just firing up a console and referring to `self`, where it isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in start_request**s**():

```
def start_requests(self):
```